# Importing 500MB .db file into phpmyadmin using a SQL dump

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I have a ~450MB .db (sqllite3) file that I need to import into my local phpmyadmin server on XAMPP. I went through the following steps to make this happen but all of them failed.

-I used sqlitebrowser to create a SQL dump of the .db file.

-When directly importing into phpmyadmin did not work I edited the php.ini to have the following properties:

- upload_max_filesize = 500MB
- post_max_size = 500MB
- memory_limit = 512MB
- max_execution_time = 3600

then tried again, without success. Even though phpmyadmin says I can import files of 500MB it still gives me a error that my file might be too large.

-I tried using both BigDump and manual CLI script for importing the dump for it but both of them return an error stating 'the system cannot find the file specified' and 'Can't open eve.sql for import'

At this point I am out of ideas. I would prefer however to make the changes to my local server so that it can import files of such size in the future as I plan to parse some YAML files and use them to update the database using a php script.

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` should be, at least, 450 MB.

Comment: have you tried to use cli `mysql`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: Sorry the upload_max_filesize was indeed 500MB, and yes I tried using that but it gives me an error that it cannot find the file. http://puu.sh/d3rdN/22e1253cfa.png

Comment: imho, try to use navicat premium.

Comment: I use Navicat Premium but I highly doubt that it can help me here. I would appreciate it if you could walk me through it please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the *mysql* command line utility

```
mysql -p -u user -h 127.0.0.1 database < data.sql
```

It usually handles big imports without problems

Comment: Unfortunately that was the mysql CLI method I mentioned I tried out. It returned me with an error 'The system cannot find the file specified' even though the file is clearly there.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path for the file and maybe using quotes: mysql -p -u user -h 127.0.0.1 database < "C:\data.sql". (If that's a windows system)

Comment: I have indeed haha. Its frustrating me as I cant see anything that I am doing wrong. I have also tried the BigDump php script for this. Had the file in the same folder and still used the absolute path and it still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using the MySQL Workbench Admin tool. It also provides interface to import sql dumps?

Comment: I am not familiar with that tool. I am using XAMPP phpmyadmin server btw. So not sure if I can access that tool.

Comment: You can get it here: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ It is pretty much a GUI replacement for the mysql command utility. I've used it to import dumps in the past without problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have one big database, use a sql-splitter or use [mysqldumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/) for import, export and querys. Works on local and live environment without need of shell (SSH) access.